# My Python for loop loops infinitely, but only when run more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make a simple algorithm that calculates a row in a pascal triangle for you, as seen in this image.

[image: A pascal triangle]

So if I wanted to know the values of the fifth row, I just input "repeat = 5" to the program, and the program spits out "[1,5,10,10,5,1]"

And I did just that using a for loop. And it works!... If you run it once, as soon as I implement a simple `for _ in range(value)` the first for loop loops infinitely. I've tried using "While (condition)" and "While True" with a break, but nothing seems to work.

```
start = [1] #This can be any of the "steps" of the pascal triangle
secondList = []
repeat = 2  # If repeat = 1 code runs fine

for _ in range(repeat):            # Without the for loop the code runs fine (But you have to manually update start.)
    print(f"First start: {start}") # Prints [1] for the first time, then [1,1]. Then it never prints again

    for idx,i in enumerate(start):

        if idx == 0:
            j = i + 0
            secondList.append(j)

        if idx == len(start)-1:
            j = i + 0
            secondList.append(j)

        else:
            j = i + start[idx+1]
            secondList.append(j)

        print(f"End of for loop, secondList: {secondList}") # Prints [1], then [1,1], then [1,1,1,2], then [1,1,1,2,2] and so on and so forth. The for loop should run once and then twice but it runs on forever.

    start = secondList # Sets the result as the start so that it can loop as many times as instructed.

print(secondList)
```

Note: The code without looping works fine, say for example, I set `start = [1,3,3,1]`(Which is row 3) and `repeat = 1` then the code spits out `[1,4,6,4,1]` (Which is the next row, row 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `secondList = []` into `for _ in range(repeat)`, before `for idx, i in ...`.

The problem in your code actually results from `start = secondList` which is invoked at the end of the first iteration. Before that, `start` and `secondList` pointed to different objects. Now you are binding them to the same object.

At the second iteration, first you didn't empty the temporary `secondList`. A more serious problem arises from the fact that `secondList.append()` *also* appends something to `start`, since they are now the same object! So each time you iterate `for idx, i in enumerate(start)`, the list `start` itself grows. So this `for` loop can never end.

So my remedy is to re-assign an empty list to `secondList`, in order to (i) re-initialize `secondList` and (ii) sever the link between this and `start`.

```py
start = [1]
repeat = 5
for _ in range(repeat):
    print(f"First start: {start}")
    secondList = []
    for idx,i in enumerate(start):
        if idx == 0:
            j = i + 0
            secondList.append(j)
        if idx == len(start)-1:
            j = i + 0
            secondList.append(j)
        else:
            j = i + start[idx+1]
            secondList.append(j)
        print(f"End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: {secondList}")
    start = secondList
print(secondList)
```

Output:

```
First start: [1]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 1]
First start: [1, 1]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 2]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 2, 1]
First start: [1, 2, 1]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 3]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 3, 3]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 3, 3, 1]
First start: [1, 3, 3, 1]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 4]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 4, 6]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 4, 6, 4]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
First start: [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 5]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 5, 10]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 5, 10, 10]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 5, 10, 10, 5]
End of the (inner) for loop, secondList: [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```